# How to connect container webserver from host browser?

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, docker, port

I am running a docker container in an office server. The container within, is running an apache2 web-server on port 80. The docker container has been run with the following command:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:80 <docker-image>
```

From outside the container, I can see the status by using curl -I 0.0.0.0:8080 which says:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 27 Oct 2021 07:00:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Tue, 19 Oct 2021 14:20:58 GMT
ETag: "468-5ceb55ec62680"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1128
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
```

Now, when I use http://0.0.0.0:8080/ in my local system browser, I am unable to see any page that is hosted by apache2.

What modification do I need to do? Am I missing anything in this?

Comment: Have you instead tried `http://127.0.0.1:8080`? Using the zero address as loopback is slightly nonstandard.

Comment: @user1686 I tired with http://<ip-address>:8080 by giving the run command as `docker run -p <ip-address>:8080:80`. This worked along with `curl -I <ip-address>:8080`.